# Parsing csv using ANTLR in c#

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have created  following grammar  in ANTLR for parsing csv file.

```
grammar CSV;

file returns [List<List<string>> data]  
@init {$data = new List<List<string>>();}  
 : (row {$data.Add($row.list);})+ EOF  
 ; 

row returns [List<string> list]  
@init {$list = new List<string>();}  
 : a=value {
        $list.Add($a.val);
    } 
    (Comma b=value {
        $list.Add($b.val);}
        )* 
        (LineBreak | EOF)  
 ;

value returns [string val]  
 : SimpleValue {$val = $SimpleValue.text;}  
 | QuotedValue   
   { 
     System.Console.WriteLine($val);
     $val = $QuotedValue.text; 
     $val = $val.Substring(1, $val.Length-1); 
     $val = $val.Replace("\"\"", "\""); 
   }  
 ;  

Comma  :
 ( ' '* ',' ' '*);

LineBreak  :
 '\r'? '\n';

SimpleValue  
 : ~[,\r\n"]+  
 ;  

QuotedValue  
 : '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"'  
 ;
```

Above grammar is parsing following csv file without error.

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

but when I am parsing following csv file it's throwing following error

```
a,b
,2
3,4

line 2:0 extraneous input ',' expecting {<EOF>, SimpleValue, QuotedValue}
```

can someone guide me how to solve this problem?

Main Program

```
 public List<List<string>> Parse()
        {
            string csvData = string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_path))
                throw new ArgumentException("Path can not be empty");

            try
            {

                csvData = File.ReadAllText(_path);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("{0} not found", _path));
            }

            // create an instance of the lexer
            CSVLexer lexer = new CSVLexer(new AntlrInputStream(csvData));

            // wrap a token-stream around the lexer
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

            // create the parser
            CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(tokens);

            // invoke the entry point of our grammar
            _results = parser.file().data;


            return _results;
        }
```

**Upadte**

As per the Mike Lischke  answer I have updated the row rule as below. Now I am not getting any error

```
row returns [List<string> list]  
@init {$list = new List<string>();}  
 : Comma? a=value {
        $list.Add($a.val);

    } 
    (Comma b=value {
        $list.Add($b.val);
        }
        )* 
        (LineBreak | EOF)  
 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your `row` rule is not flexible enough to handle missing values. You should use something like this instead:

```
row: Comma? value (Comma value)*;
```

which adds the possibility for a leading comma (actually a missing first value).

And a recommendation: don't use action code in your grammar to collect the values. Instead create and assign a parse listener to your parser whose methods are triggered during parsing to do all the background work. It keeps the grammar a lot cleaner and allows to use it indepent of the actual target language.

Comment: How to add the row rule in my grammer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. How to you add any text to your grammar?

Comment: I have updated my question. After making changes suggested by you.now I am not getting any error